# Favorites Folders in Evolution

Tags: email, evolution

Is there a way to create a list of Favorites folders in Evolution and list them above the regular folder structure, much like we can do in Outlook?

Thanks in advance to the community for their help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old thread I know but I've been looking for a similar option. The following is the best that I can come up with:

Edit -> Search Folders then Click [Add]. The Rule name will appear as the name of the favourite. Set the condition as "To contains @" then [Add] a specific folder to the folder you want as your favourite and tick "Automatically update on any source folder change".

[Looks a bit like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdwK7.png)

Create a new Search Folders rule for each favourite folder.

To make them appear at the top of Side Bar go to Edit -> Preferences -> Mail Accounts and drag Search Folders to the top of the list.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: As of Evolution 3.39.2, you can just set the Source folders of a Search folder to the folders you want to include, and then set the condition to Match All. Works like a charm, and in fact ultimately this seems more flexible/customizable than the Unified folders of Thunderbird. Thanks for pointing me to this!